# License concerns of using Ubuntu's color scheme and fonts in an open-source app

Tags: fonts, open-source, legal

I am developer who is creating a new free and open-source web application. Does anyone know if it's OK to use Ubuntu's color scheme and fonts for this?

Comment: Why would you? The colors are the worst part of Ubuntu.

Comment: I rather love them , I just don't want lawsuits for using them.

Comment: Fonts can be copyrighted, colours cannot... IMO.

Comment: Please note that most people here are no lawyers, which means our legal advice is nothing you can rely surely on and we can not be made responsible for any consequences in case we're wrong... Your best action would probably be to write an email at Canonical and ask for official permission.

Answer (score 1):

These three snippets were taken from the official Ubuntu [Intellectual property rights policy](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy) webpage.

> Canonical owns and manages certain intellectual property rights in Ubuntu and other associated intellectual property (Canonical IP) and licenses the use of these rights to enterprises, individuals and members of the Ubuntu community in accordance with this IPRights Policy.
>
> *Use of Canonical's copyright, patent and design materials*
>
> - You can only use Canonical’s copyright materials in accordance with the copyright licenses therein and this IPRights Policy.
> - You cannot use Canonical’s patented materials without our permission.
>
> *Trade dress and look and feel*
>
> Canonical owns intellectual property rights in the trade dress and look and feel of Ubuntu (including the Unity interface), along with various themes and components that may include unregistered design rights, registered design rights and design patents, your use of Ubuntu is subject to these rights.

Ubuntu's color scheme and fonts falls under the category of *various themes and components* in the last paragraph of the preceding text block.